# Possible bug in Visual Studio 2010 linker (minimal testcase included)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Here is minimal test example, which makes my Visual Studio 2010 crashed during linkage in `Release` mode. (just an example, no meaningful code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    typedef std::function<void()> Func;

    Func m_func;
    float m_f;

    Foo(Func func, float f)
       :m_func(func),
        m_f(f)
    {
        func();
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    Bar(): foo(std::bind(&Bar::bar, this), 1.0f)
    {
        std::cout << "foobar";
    }

    Foo foo;
    void bar(){ std::cout << "bar"; }
};

int main()   
{
    Bar b;
}
```

output:

```
 fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c[0x5AE87EF6:0x00000009]', line 183)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>  
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
1>  
1>    Version 10.00.40219.01
1>  
1>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>    ExceptionAddress         = 5AE87EF6 (5AE40000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\c2.dll"
1>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00000009
1>  
1>  CONTEXT:
1>    Eax    = 040570CC  Esp    = 0042ED34
1>    Ebx    = 5B09E2A8  Ebp    = 0042ED4C
1>    Ecx    = 0405660C  Esi    = 04010660
1>    Edx    = 00000000  Edi    = 0000001E
1>    Eip    = 5AE87EF6  EFlags = 00010287
1>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

In Debug mode it builds just fine.

When `func()` is not called it builds just fine.

When `float` is changed to `int` it builds just fine. (??)

Is this a compiler bug? Can somebody reproduce it?

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate 10.0.40219.1 SP1

Comment: The problem does not reproduce on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1

Comment: As the message says "To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ ". Not sure what Stack Overflow can do here.

Comment: possibly related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800094/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a crash in any program is a bug, unless crashing is one of the features of that program (there are no programs that I know of that advertise crashing as a feature).

You're best off sending the error report or taking it directly to the MS forums.

Comment: Unless the crash is caused by something external to the program.

Comment: Or a corrupted installation.

Comment: the crash is reproductible on my 10.0.40219.1 SP1 install

Comment: @PlasmaHH crashing the debugger? Wait - the unit tests crash the debugger?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: the unit tests are programs that crash, and the debugger is fed with them and should behave well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It occurred after having deleted empty destructos.
After restoring them the problem disappeared.
I didn't try it on the example above, but my suggestion is to add:

~Foo() {}

~Bar() {}